# .bib generate space extra

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, natbib, abbrvnat.bst

I doing my thesis work. This my sample code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
%================================================================================
%Bib. style
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat-esp}
%================================================================================
\usepackage{geometry} %Margenes
\geometry{
asymmetric, %Emula el diseño de report
marginpar=2.1cm, %Para notas
top=3cm, %Encabezado
lmargin=3.5cm, %Margen izq.
rmargin=3cm, %Margen derecho
}
%================================================================================
\usepackage[
  pdfstartview=XYZ, %Auto ajuste de la pag
  bookmarksnumbered, %N\'umero
  colorlinks=true, %Permite el cambio de colores
  linkcolor=blue, %Colores internos
  citecolor=red, %Bibliografia en azul
]{hyperref}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\begin{document}
\include{Grassmann}
%Bibliografia
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibliografia}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliograf\'ia}
\end{document}
```

This the PDF **without compile the .bib file**:

[image]

And, this is **with compile .bib file**:
[image]

The same page, but with extra space. I would like remove the extra space, any suggestion?

**Extra**: TexMaker and TeXstudio, generate the same result.

Comment: The problem is simple: the big table of values doesn't fit in the page, so it's moved to the next one. The class you are using has `\flushbottom` in force. It's not a bibliography problem, but just caused by the length of the paragraph with the citations.

Comment: @egreg I need rewrite my sentences to remove the space, right?

Comment: That's it, I'm afraid